# How do you align text of one item in nav?

Tags: html, css

I am building a navigation bar using `<nav>` and I am aligning the text to the right but I want to get the logo in the navbar to be on the left I have tried many ways to move it like giving it a id and using `!important` but it still wont move

Here is my relevant HTML

```
<div id="navDiv">
    <nav>
        <a href="me.html" id="logo">Name</a>
        <a href="home.html">Home</a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
        <a href="mailto:email@example.com">Contact</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS

```
#logo
{
    text-align:left !important;
}

nav
{
    text-align:right;
}
```

Why is the logo element still on the right when `!important` is telling it to go to the left and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to the "Name" to appear to the left while everything else is to the right? So, like this: http://jsbin.com/gejefiji/1/edit

The only thing I did there is add a `float: left;` to the `#logo` selector.

The reason the `nav` rule overrides the `#logo` rule even with the `!important` is due to nesting. The `nav` itself is a block element, meaning it expands to fill its container. The `a` tags are not block elements, they are inline, meaning they follow the alignment rules for the containing element, which means they get text-aligned right. If you inspect the elements in the layout section of your browser's development tools, you can see that the width of the `a` elements shrinks-to-fit the content, like so:

[image]

The text *inside* the `a#logo` is left-aligned, but the elements themselves are right-aligned, so it appears to not follow what you want.

If you do use the `float: left`, I strongly recommend you look into adding where and when to use a `clear: left` element after your nav, just to prevent any float properties form interfering with the rest of the page's layout. Emre's `nav:after` trick is handy, but is not supported on all browsers, so you might need a separate element with a specific class assigned to it, like this:

```
// CSS
.clear {
    clear: left;
}

// HTML
    </nav> <!-- after the nav -->
</div> <!-- or after the div -->
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Basically, you want to put the `clear` before anything else that you *don't* want floated.

Comment: Yep that is what I was looking to do

Answer (score 2):

add `float:left;`

```
#logo
{
    float:left;
}
nav
{
    text-align:right;
}
```

Live demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fc4Zw/)

Answer (score 1):

The `text-align` property can only be applied to  box-level item that *contains* items to be aliged either left or right -- not on the items themselves. So you can't have some items inside nav text-aligned left and some text-aligned right this way.

You can, however, float the logo left:

```
#logo{float:left;}
```

Answer (score 1):

here it is :) that should work well [tested]

```
  <style>

    nav
    {
        text-align:right;
    }
    #logo
    {
        float:left;
    }
    nav:after { /* fix float */
        visibility: hidden; 
        display: block; 
        font-size: 0; 
        content: " "; 
        clear: both; 
        height: 0; 
    }
    </style>
    <div id="navDiv">
        <nav>
            <a href="me.html" id="logo">Name</a>
            <a href="home.html">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
            <a href="mailto:email@example.com">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: That works almost right but now #logo is on the bottom of the nav bar and the other elements are in the middle of the navs height.

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not use float?

```
#logo {
  float:left;
}
```